# Ask Question app should have side-by-side view option

Tags: feature-request, design, se-sites

Though I have long grown accustomed to the vertical layout of the "Ask Question" app.  I realize now, that it is probably a great bug to request be fixed.  You notice, right, when you're working on a math question, that editing past 50 or so lines becomes cumbersome?  Right, I have to keep scrolling up and down, up and down, and the MathJax content (I'm guessing) makes it so that this up/down scrolling is not even fluid (useable). The end result is that this bug is identified as a **major bottleneck** for any mathematical pursuit involving MSE.  One pseudo-solution I've found is to zoom out the page, but that of course is limited by your content length (when it grows huge) too.

I have *some credibility* when it comes to UI design.  I have written a complicated 60+ Python 3 file PyQt5 app.  And maybe 5 other tiny PyQt5 apps.  I am also a 10+ year user of web pages, like most of us, so can judge what is a good design and what is not.  Also, this is not some crazy futuristic feature request, but actually something the site engineers could, ideally, whip together in a few weeks.

### Feature Request:

The simplest solution is to allow a checkbox option on the Ask Question page (for desktop sessions only; not mobile) that toggles between *vertical* and *horizontal* views.  Vertical viewing is what we already have.  Horizontal viewing is putting the text edit box on the left, and the MathJax post previewer on the right, so that on a standard laptop, the user can view both sides no mater how long their post becomes.  Additionally, the side-by-side (horizontal) viewing auto-scrolls to your current place of editing.  This results in less needless stress for every actively participating MSE user!

The current MO of the Ask Question app in regard to long posts is very troublesome to me, so I have also tagged this post with "bug", as it is by definition a UI design bug. Please give your support for a better-working MSE site by voting this up and commenting.

Comment: Imagine if we had to use vertical viewing in $\LaTeX$ documents...

Comment: I don't think this is a bug by the way. The behaviour is fully intended, whether or not it is a poor choice. An example of a UI bug might be the `\tag` mathjax command which spills over into the right-hand column.

Comment: Probably a duplicate? [Feature request - but it woudn't be a feature, it'd be a blessing - editing panel and preview side-by-side - fighting lag on large answers!](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10505) You can find some useful links in the comments and also [other linked discussions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/10505) might be of interested.

Comment: Meta.SO: [Question and preview might be better side-by-side](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70703). StackApps: [Stack Exchange Side-By-Side Edit and Preview](http://stackapps.com/q/2245)

Comment: BTW somewhat unusual choice of tags. Maybe you used the tag ([meta-tag:se-sites]) to indicate that you want to ask about this change on all sites in the SE networks. [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) is the site for network-wide discussions and feature requests. (But it is perfectly find to discuss them also locally.) If I had to choose suitable tags, it would probably be ([meta-tag:markdown-preview]) and ([meta-tag:editor]).