# Finding MathJax mistakes (or general mistakes) in your (soon to be posted) question/answer more easily

Tags: feature-request, editing, editor

Often when I post a question or answer which gets a little bit longer and I make a mistake somewhere in this post, I tend to find it fairly difficult to find the spot in the text/code where I want to add or fix something.

Would it be possible to involve some 'shortcuts' in the text, shown below (which converts your text immediately) to the spots in your written text, so if you click on a specific word you immediately get to the point in your text field?

I hope it is clear what I am asking for.

Little example for clarification:

I write something and find out the code has a failure at some point $A$.
I do not find the point where I have to fix something in my text, because the answer is rather long/complex.

So I would like to click on $A$ in the output to get to that specific point immediately in my written code.

Thanks for reading/commenting.

Comment: ShareLaTeX / Overleaf has a feature like this, so it can clearly *be* done.  However, I wouldn't hold my breath with regards to such a feature on SE.  The network is a lot bigger than just mathematics, and my guess is that there is not strong institutional support for such a feature (prove me wrong, SE overlords!).

Comment: It's not what you're asking for, but having editing window and rendered output side-by-side might make finding the place with the problem a bit easier. On this meta you can find [this feature request with rather long title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10505). Another related post is: [Ask Question app should have side-by-side view option](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25179). In the comments you  can find links to some related posts on [meta.se].

Comment: This feature request on [meta.se] seems similar to yours: [Position cursor at approximate area while clicking on preview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156656). One of the answers mentions this userscript: [Dude, where's my cursor?](https://stackapps.com/q/3894). I haven't tried it myself, the author [provides a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZMqQ07HkuU) illustrating the usage.

Comment: I was not sure whether to add the ([meta-tag:mathjax]) tag. In the title you mention MathJax, however the same issue makes sense also for the text outside MathJax. (Just a typo, or some problem with [meta-tag:markdown], dead link, etc.)